# C# How do I append a Cell to every Row in a Excel Sheet using OpenXmlWriter (OpenXML SDK 2.5)

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a very large Excel file where I need to append 100 new Cells to each row.
Because the OpenXML DOM approach is giving me a OutOfMemory Exception I need to use OpenXmlWriter for my project.

Can anyone here tell me please how I can append cells to a row using OpenXmlWriter?

This is my code using the DOM approach:

```
                int nRowCounter = 0;
                foreach (Row row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    // skip first row
                    nRowCounter++;
                    if (nRowCounter == 1)
                        continue;


                    string uniqueID = row.Elements<Cell>().First().InnerText;


                    string[] branchenOfId = crmConnector.GetBranchenFromCrm(uniqueID, "");

                    if (listSelectedBranchen.Any() && !branchenOfId.Intersect(listSelectedBranchen).Any() && nBranchenIndex == 1)
                    {
                        rowsToRemove.Add(row.RowIndex.Value);
                        continue;
                    }

                    string cellValue = "";

                    if (branchenOfId.Contains(strName))
                        cellValue = strName;

                    row.Append(new Cell() { DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(cellValue) });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
{

WorkbookPart workBookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

//You can retrieve a specific sheet also by the following code
IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "Sheet Name");

//find the first row in the sheet data
Row row1 = sheetData.GetFirstChild<Row>();

//create a new cell
//I is the column and 1 is the Row Index
// I assume you know how to get the last column of any row. 
//Just get the next alphabet letter and add the row index to make a CellReference.
//e.g. If last cell of the Row is H, you can get the next letter i-e I
Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = "I1" };
CellFormula cellformula = new CellFormula();
cellformula.Text = "IF(A2 = A1,1,0)";
cell.Append(cellformula);

//append the cell to the row
row1.Append(cell);
}
```

Also have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278309.aspx) documentation link

Comment: This is the DOM approach. But I need to use the OpenXmlWriter.

Comment: Have a look at the following link how to use OpenXmlWriter for big files. http://polymathprogrammer.com/2012/08/06/how-to-properly-use-openxmlwriter-to-write-large-excel-files/ it is explained with an example.